# get value of a child of a child of a key in JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

We are using Firebase and vue.js for a web app. The web app is supposed to retrieve photos' url (it can be any number of photos), along with their description and their location.

We manage to retrieve the photos' url, their description, but not their location.

The database structure is as follow:

[image]

JS:

```
db.ref('photos/' + owneruid + '/trips/' + tripuid).once('value').then(snap => {
 var photos = snap.val()
 for (var key in photos) {
     console.log(key)
     this.photos.push(photos[key])
 }
 this.photosDataIsReady = true
```

HTML:

```
<li v-for="photo in photos" v-if="photosDataIsReady === true">
    <img v-bind:src="photo.photourl" />
    <span class="photo-desc">{{photo.desc}}</span>

    {{photo.location.coord}}

</li>
```

And here is the console output:

[image]

So basically it retrieves the gps coordinates for the 1st photo only, but not the other ones.

EDIT: Actually the problem comes from the fact that some photos don't have any location set. The child "location" doesn't exist:

[image]

So how can we loop over location, and ignore when it doesn't exist so that the loop still continues?

Comment: I think you're looking for `db.ref('photos/' + owneruid + '/trips/' + tripuid).orderByKey().limitToFirst(1).once('value')`

Comment: Thanks Frank, but this is only giving me the first photo in the object. I would like to get all photos, along with their urls, description and location. So far I get all urls with v-bind:src="photo.photourl" and all description with {{photo.desc}}, but getting the location with {{photo.location.coord}} doesn't work

Comment: Actually see my EDIT in the post, I found where the problem comes from

Comment: `snap.val().location.locationName` but you are going to have to iterate over all of the the photo items. So a vanilla `for` loop on `snap.val()` which will include multiple children

Comment: Thanks Ron ! Though I still have the issue that in some photos, the children "location.coord" doesn't exist (see my EDIT). So the loop doesn't work. How can we prevent a loop from stopping if the children "location" doesn't exist ?